# fail2ban-regex <HOST> filter missed

Tags: fail2ban

quick question regarding fail2ban filter regex problem
I have a log pattern:

*2018-02-06 07:40:20,954 fail2ban.actions [26058]: NOTICE [postfix-sasl] Ban* 192.168.2.14

I try to Ban IP (192.168.2.14) following filter:

*failregex = ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} ([a-z])\w+.([a-z])\w+ [\d*]: NOTICE [([a-z])\w+-([a-z])\w+] Ban *

So far no luck.
fail2ban-regex listed missing line

I am sure it is a simple error somewhere in the middle.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You have already banned this IP address. Banning it again is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would like to block an IP with fail2ban that has been blocked already with fail2ban, but anyway …

I see two issues why your fail2ban filter does not work.

1. You don't have a `<HOST>` tag within your failregex line.

   Replace `*` at the end of your failregex line by `<HOST>`. This will tell fail2ban witch part of a log file line represents the IP to ban.
2. Your regex is not correct.

   Replace

   ```
   ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} ([a-z])\w+.([a-z])\w+ [\d]: NOTICE [([a-z])\w+-([a-z])\w+] Ban <HOST>
   ```

   by

   ```
   ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \w+\.\w+ \[.*\]: NOTICE \[\w+\-\w+\] Ban <HOST>
   ```

   or even more simply expressed

   ```
   ^\.* Ban <HOST>$
   ```